# Eclipse doesn't stay "Always on Visible Workspace"

Tags: centos, gnome, desktop, eclipse, workspaces

I usually hop between a few workspaces, but like having a couple of frequently used applications "Always on Visible Workspace". However, when I tell Eclipse to do that it slips into "Only on This Workspace" after the next major eclipse operation such as compilation.

I find that very surprising: I thought that workspace affinity was handled by gnome, not by the specific application, so there should be no reason why terminal and firefox would honor that and eclipse wouldn't.

Thus the question: why (and how) eclipse slips between "Always on Visible Workspace" and "Only on This Workspace", and how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

If the window is deleted and recreated, then the window manager (gnome) loses the setting.  This happens to me with pidgin chat windows if I ever close them.  I don't know if eclipse does this on major state transitions (edit->build), but watch for gnome's tab order to change, or the window to completely vanish for a moment.

I'd really like to be able to associate settings like this with window names, like ctwm could.